# Do popovers serves as the starch and the bread in a meal?

Tags: menu-planning

I found an interesting recipe for Roquefort popovers and wanted to serve along side of filet mignon and grilled lobster tail, with potatoes and salad.  Should I leave out the potatoes?

Answer (score 1):

I personally would skip the potatoes. Though bread is a standard accompaniment for meals, unless the bread is interesting I fail to see the point. So if you do have an interesting bread, skip the other starchy parts of the dish as unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna have two forms of protein, might as well go whole hog on the starch as well. Symmetry, you know? Though in that case, I'd think about adding a cooked vegetable in addition to the (presumably uncooked) salad.

Comment: I like your suggestion.  I am going "whole hog" because I always wanted to try popovers and what a great way to start the new year.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the rest of your menu. If it is a rich menu with a lot of courses, maybe it is wise to leave out the potatoes for that reason.